# What does appending " ' " like a', b' so on means in F#

Tags: f#

I've just started out learning F# language and there this thing that got me confused and i can't seem to find an explanation for it.

So what i want to know is why people append '(single quote) symbol in the bindings like example here:

```
let var x' = x + 1, or
let newList<T'> = new List<T>
```

I've tried looking up the MSDN library and there is no mention of its usage. So i guess it must be a convention. But for what purpose ?

Thanx

Comment: maybe 'x? it's generic.

Comment: I don't think a single quote as a suffix has any special meaning. However, as a prefix [it definitely does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx).

Comment: Thanx mike, i almost missed that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a convention from [mathematical notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29#Use_in_mathematics.2C_statistics.2C_and_science). `x'` is pronounced "X prime" and essentially indicates that the variable is a modified version of `x`. It doesn't particularly mean anything to the language — it's just a naming convention.

Comment: This and together with mike's comment succinctly undid my confusion. Thank you.